# Page Layout in Change Set

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, change-set

I Added Page Layout to outbound change set, added profiles to change set and deployed it in Production but page layouts were unchanged in production. What is the reason?

Comment: did you checked the page layout assignment?

Comment: @sanketkumar I have only one page layout on this object and it is assigned to all profiles

Comment: Strange, can you try workaround mentioned (https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000epA6QAI)